# Task Default Not Found , despite mentioning the Default Task

Tags: gruntjs

There are questions ask before but I couldn't get much out of them as I'm new to grunt.Whenever I run code , Console reads as follows

> SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
>   Warning: Task "default" not found. Use --force to continue.

My code is:

```js
'use strict';

module.exports = function (grunt) {
 // Time how long tasks take. Can help when optimizing build times
  require('time-grunt')(grunt);

 // Automatically load required Grunt tasks
  require('jit-grunt')(grunt, {
  useminPrepare: 'grunt-usemin'
});
 
  // Define the configuration for all the tasks
  
  
  grunt.initConfig({
   
   pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

  // Make sure code styles are up to par and there are no obvious mistakes
  jshint: {
    options: {
      jshintrc: '.jshintrc',
      reporter: require('jshint-stylish')
    },
    
    all: {
      src: [
        'Gruntfile.js',
        'app/scripts/{,*/}*.js'
      ]
    }
  },

    useminPrepare: {
 html: 'app/menu.htm 
 },

useminPrepare: {
  html: 'app/menu.html',
  options: {
    dest: 'dist'
  }
},

// Concat
concat: {
  options: {
    separator: ';'
  },
  
  // dist configuration is provided by useminPrepare
  dist: {}
},

// Uglify
uglify: {
  // dist configuration is provided by useminPrepare
  dist: {}
},

cssmin: {
  dist: {}
},

// Filerev
filerev: {
  options: {
    encoding: 'utf8',
    algorithm: 'md5',
    length: 20
  },
  
  release: {
    // filerev:release hashes(md5) all assets (images, js and css )
    // in dist directory
    files: [{
      src: [
        'dist/scripts/*.js',
        'dist/styles/*.css',
      ]
    }]
  }
},
  
// Usemin
// Replaces all assets with their revved version in html and css files.
// options.assetDirs contains the directories for finding the assets
// according to their relative paths
usemin: {
  html: ['dist/*.html'],
  css: ['dist/styles/*.css'],
  options: {
    assetsDirs: ['dist', 'dist/styles']
  }
},
copy: {
  dist: {
    cwd: 'app',
    src: [ '**','!styles/**/*.css','!scripts/**/*.js' ],
    dest: 'dist',
    expand: true
  },
  
  fonts: {
    files: [
      {
        //for bootstrap fonts
        expand: true,
        dot: true,
        cwd: 'bower_components/bootstrap/dist',
        src: ['fonts/*.*'],
        dest: 'dist'
      }, {
        //for font-awesome
        expand: true,
        dot: true,
        cwd: 'bower_components/font-awesome',
        src: ['fonts/*.*'],
        dest: 'dist'
      }
    ]
  }
},

clean: {
  build: {
    src: [ 'dist/']
  }
  }   
  });
 
  grunt.registerTask('build', [
  'clean',
  'jshint',
  'useminPrepare',
  'concat',
  'cssmin',
  'uglify',
  'copy',
  'filerev',
  'usemin'
]);

  grunt.registerTask('default' , ['build']);
};
```

Comment: are you calling grunt from the same directory as your grunfile is in? also do you specify any arguments?

Comment: Yes, I'm calling grunt from the same directory

Answer (score 0):

the complete output of your grunt call shows that your `gruntfile.js` has a sytax error:

> Loading "gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR 
>   >> SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token Warning: Task "default" not found. Use --force to continue.
>
> Aborted due to warnings.

and indeed your file has no closing quotes on line **37**:

```
useminPrepare: {
  html: 'app/menu.htm  <-----!!!!!!!!
},

useminPrepare: {
  html: 'app/menu.html',
  options: {
    dest: 'dist'
  }
},
```

probably a copy paste error since you have the **useminPrepare** twice (which is illegal in strict mode btw...)